# Reducing the number of Google Map API calls by using Open Street Map tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps-api

I have a website that is exceeding the Google Maps API free limit.  I am wondering if by switching over to Open Street Map as the default tile layer (replacing Google Maps Street layer) if I will reduce the number of API calls?

I am planning on switching over to Leaflet, but that will take longer.

---

I am paying for each map load. So using Open Street Maps will not help.

> How are map loads counted on the Google Maps Platform?  A single map
>   load is charged when any of the following occur:
>
> - A web page or application displays a map using the Maps JavaScript    API.
> - An application requests a single map image from the Maps Static    API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload